# AngularJS dependant inputs link to the same scope variable

Tags: angularjs, input, infinite-loop

I'm new to angularJS and I'm trying to design a form including 2 input fields which are internally tied to the same scope variable: saying the first field is the speed in km/h and the second field is the speed in m/s. The behavior I'd like to obtain is: whatever field the user changes the other field would be updated.

The problem I'm running into is the following:

When the speed in m/s is changed by the user, the speed in km/h is updated which lead to update again the speed in m/s, which update the speed in km/h until no value change. The side effect is when the speed in m/s is a round number saying 1 and the user change the value to make it decimal entering the decimal dot - the update loop lead to remove the dot because from a calculus point of view 1. is 1.

What is the best way to avoid that?

Here are the fragments of code (html):

```
  <label for="SpeedKm">Speed (Km/h):</label>
  <input id="SpeedKm" name="SpeedKm" type="text" 
    placeholder="km/h"  
    ng-model="speedKmh"
    ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true}">
  >
  <label for="SpeedMs">Speed (m/s):</label>
  <input id="SpeedMs" name="SpeedMs" type="text" 
    placeholder="m/s"  
    ng-model="speedMs"
    ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true}">
  >
```

and the controller

```
angular.module('speedconverter') 
 .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.speed = 10; //km/h
   $scope.speedKmh = function(newValue) {
     if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
       $scope.speed = newValue;
     }
     return $scope.speed;
   };
   $scope.speedms = function(newValue) {
     if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
       $scope.speed = newValue*3.6;
     }
     return $scope.speed/3.6;
   };
 });
```

Thank you

Comment: so you want the values in the textboxes to be coefficients of each other, and basically want angular to only calculate changes based on user input, not on calculated input?  I don't really think that the `$digest` loop supports this kind of logic.

Comment: don't use a function for ng-model. Seems that all you really need is to use event handling